# Heyawake - how to continue?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Can you help me find the next move. (The cells marked with dots must be white).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the square area with the four, there's only one way to fit the black squares in there.

Comment: Doh. I am stupid.